# Are there any libraries for vector QR codes in PHP

Tags: php, vector, generator, qr-code

I know that there are are 3rd party APIs such as Google for generating QR codes and I have used Phpqrcode library but that is for generating bitmap images and I would like to be able to generate vector QR codes if this is possible? That way I could scale them up for print.

Does anybody know of any libraries that could be used or for instance a JavaScript API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you checked out [Zint](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/)? I believe it can output in many different formats.

Comment: Thank you julio, that is awesome! In case anyone else finds this, and wants to know, the barcode type option (-b) to use is 58